# How do I make a custom tileset for Flixel that supports autotiling?

Tags: flash, tiles, flixel

I've been Googling this problem for a while now. I'm currently porting one of my Java games to Flixel, and I want to use the original 16x16 tileset I made. In the original game I implemented my own autotiling system, but I would prefer to use Flixel's autotiling system. However, I cannot determine how to lay out my tileset, or how to tell Flixel to use it. I have two different types of tiles, and I want both types to autotile to connect with tiles of the same type but not tiles of the other type, if possible.

Comment: http://flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tiled Use something like Tiled to do it for you. And you then you just read the map into flixel.

Comment: btw this is the official website: http://www.mapeditor.org/

Comment: Thanks, I might end up using that. However, that's a tilemap editor, and what I'm looking for is a way to lay out a tileset.

Comment: It comes with a feature that allows you to make tilesets that automatically adapt to different tilesets. It's called a Terrain in that editor. I assumed you meant that.